# Failed to import transformers.onnx.config

Tags: python, dll, sentence-transformers

> Failed to import transformers.onnx.config due to DLL load failed while
> importing _imaging: The specified module could not be found.

[image]

Already updated Pillow. `pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Comment: This solved the issue: conda install -c conda-forge sentence-transformers